STM32F103C8T6 -> USB unknown driver error: descriptor request failed
Hello fellow developers.
I have switched from Arduino to create & learn with custom STM32 boards. Followed a tutorial on how to make a simple STM32 breakout board. The design matches the tutorial and datasheet from STM32. However, the boards have arrived and I have a USB connection issue with all my 5 PCB's.
Been looking for 2 days on this forum and other sites for similar solutions. I think I can conclude it has nothing to do with drivers but most likely hardware issue.
Issue: When powering PCB in PROGR / RUN mode ( BOOT0), the USB gives a beep in Windows but I get the error in device manager : unknown driver error ( descriptor request failed ).
Fix attempts, without solution:

Other Desktops, other OS ( win10 & win11 ), other USB micro to USB A cables
Measured the boot0 pin, this is either 0V or 3.3V when switching the boot selector switch.
Desoldered the oscillator, hoping there is an issue and the internal oscillator will take over
Desoldered the pull-up resistor on D+ USB pin, this gives the result -> no detect in Windows
Measured all VDD and VSS pins on the microcontroller, OK.
Compared my design with the STM32 Blue Pill design, almost identical connections and STM32 type
I have 5 identical PCB's manufactured, all of them fail.

Another weird thing I found, is that when powering on the board, almost all IO pins are default +-2VDC or even 3.3DVC. Is this normal that a blank STM32 has all the IO pins high or floating high???
PS: the pin headers are not soldered yet and nothing is connected to the board. Its blank and never used before. First try. Also the 5VBUS to 3.3V convertor is not in this schematic, just to avoid too much info. That convertor works fine.
I really hope you can help me, I'm nearly giving up on this... With love and many thanks, wouter.




I appreciate the visual and the schematic image, but a screenshot of the actual board design outside of the 3D renderer would be helpful to ensure that there aren't any missed connections. Would you mind editing your question to include that/those?

You neither mention an ST-Link adapter nor your code. The STM32F103 MCU does not have an USB boot loader. So code must be uploaded either via ST-Link/debug adapter or over UART (PA9/PA10). And the USB port will only become active if your code contains the required USB code. How do you upload code? And is your code actually using the USB port?

The default STM32 internal bootloader works for SWD and USART, as per your BOOT configuration, it should works with SWD. To use the USB, you will need to have the code related to USB (i.e. a special boot loader) to be uploaded. Your circuit looks like the typical Blue Pill design with a couple of correction on its design faults, but does not have the circuitry for USB enumeration as shown in this design.

“the manual says this: …” This sounds like the manual of a more recent STM32 MCU as the STM32F103 only supports UART and SWD. Get a ST-Link adapter. It’s inexpensive and also very useful for debugging. You have connections for it.

Thank you mate. I found a PL2303TA USB to TTL adapter for UART programming. I will buy one and try to get a connection open with my MCU. As long as I can do something with the boards is fine by me. USB is not mandatory. Just easy to use. Will give you an update in 2 days when the part has arrived.

Hi guys, got my UART. Connect all pins. Sadly, still cant CONNECT via CubeProgrammer. I did notice something. When I swap rxd & txd, get instant : Error, device KO. However, when I connect properly, I can see some communication: 14:12:07 : UR connection mode is defined with the HWrst reset mode
14:12:07 : RTS low
14:12:07 : DTR low
14:12:08 : Serial Port COM3 is successfully opened.
14:12:08 : Port configuration: parity = even, baudrate = 115200, data-bit = 8,                     stop-bit = 1.0, flow-control = off
14:12:12 : Activating device: OK
14:12:12 : Board       : --

The serial terminal stops with this :   14:12:15 : Timeout error occured while waiting for acknowledgement.
14:12:15 : Error: GETID command not acknowledged!
14:12:15 : Chip ID: 0x0 .......          Is this a sign the MCU is actually working? Is it possible the MCU chip is as good as Factory Blank and I should purchase the STLink programmer?

It is not enough to just following some PCB design tutorial to design a MCU development board without reading Getting started with stm32f10xxx hardware development which described the various boot options. UART Bootloader is in system memory, so you need to set Boot0 to HIGH, and BOOT1 to LOW. Press the Reset button on the board prior uploading so that the board enters UART bootloader mode from the System Memory.

Thank HCheung, I have tried already adding the BOOT1 concept with a solder wire to ground or VDD. couldnt see any difference. I have currently stopped with STM32 and moved to ESP32. If my new ESP32 PCB works, I will quit on STM32. Is there a way to close the ticket here as such?
